# HTMLAGILITYPACK IEnumerable nodes?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
string dadada(IEnumerable _elements)
{
    int i = 0;
    string link = "null";

    foreach (HtmlNode node in _elements)
    {
        i++;

        if (i == 2)
        {
            link = node.SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes[0].Value;
        }
    }

    return link;
}
```

How do I make this better as this code works but is cancer!

Please let me understand!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd change the method to accept an `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` instead of a generic IEnumerable. This might or might not require changes on the calling side, but it prevents your method from being called, for example, with an integer array.

Then, you can use LINQs `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault` to get rid of the loop. The latter returns `null` if the enumerable does not contain enough elements.

```
string dadada(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> _elements)
{
    HtmlNode node = _elements.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

    return node == null ? "null" : node.SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: it is when i == 2! sorry!

Comment: @Andrew: Just use `Skip(1)` before `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
string dadada(IEnumerable _elements)
{
    string link = "null";

    if(_elements.Count() > 1)
    {
        link = ((HtmlNode)_elements.Skip(1).First()).SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes[0].Value;
    }

    return link;
}
```

Comment: it is when i == 2! sorry!